# How to verify whether two SQL Server databases contain equal data?

Tags: sql-server, testing, verify

Given two MS SQL databases which are known to have identical schemas, how should I tell whether they contain identical copies of the data?

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 Express, and coding in C# and v2.0 of the .Net framework, using ADO.NET APIs. The two database instances are both on the same SQL server.

Background: I've written software to export data from a database to a set of files, and, to re-import the data from those files (into another copy of the database); I want to test whether I lost any data during the round-trip (more specifically, whether there's any data lost or left behind during the initial export).

A crude way I guess would be to `SELECT *` from every table in each database, and then to compare the selected recordsets using client-side code. Is there another way, that would require less client-side code?

I've found documentation about backing up and restoring a database, and about selecting and inserting data, but haven't noticed this about how to verify/prove that a round-trip has been completely successful, i.e. how to verify whether two copies of a table in two databases contain equal data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be to compare record counts.  You can do this with a quick

```
select count('x') from TAbleY
```

You would need to do this for every Table.

To compare the data in the tables I would use the [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258245(SQL.80).aspx) function.

Comment: Thanks; I see now that there's also a CHECKSUM_AGG function which can be used to take a checksum over every row in a table. http://dbwhisperer.blogspot.com/2009/02/checksumagg-very-nifty-function.html suggests combining CHECKSUM with CHECKSUM_AGG, for QA applications.

Answer (score 1):

RedGate's [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) might be the answer.

Comment: That product has more functionality than I'm asking for, but its existence suggests that perhaps even the basic functionality isn't built-in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redgate SQL DATA COMPARE
1>It will tell total count of data in each table of your database
2> It will generate a script which will show what data is different in it so that by executing          it you can make data same.
3>It will show if schema is different by SQL COMPARE
4>Lots of features are useful you can also sync two database.

Addition to it Visual studio 2012 gives you an option to compare the data ,You can try that also